# How to bind HTML5 datepicker and other input types using Knockout.js?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, datepicker, cross-browser

I started to learn knockout.js and faced some issues while working with html5 form fields. When I am dealing with html5 input field elements which have text type then everything goes well, but unfortunately I cannot get and display values from html5 datepicker which type is date.

I found some examples that describe data-binding with datepickers in KnockoutJS, but they use some other sources (for example moment.js or jQuery UI) in order to achieve needed result.

Therefore could you give me any idea about binding html5 datepicker inputs with KnockoutJS without including any additional plugins and libraries, and without using computed variables?

Apart from that, I even did not find any references in KO's official documentation that explain how to work with HTML5's new input types such as color, email, url, number, range and some others. Therefore, I would highly appreciate if you could give me any hint.

```html
<h2>Set date</h2>
<!--input type "text" works well and the result is visible below whereas other input types are problematic-->
<input type="text" data-bind="value: addStart" /><br> 

From <input  type="date" data-bind="date: addStartDate" /> 
To <input type="date" data-bind="date: addEndDate" />

<input  type="color" data-bind="date: addColor" /> 
<input type="email" data-bind="date: addEmail" />
<input type="url" data-bind="date: addUrl" />
<input type="number" data-bind="date: addNumber" />
<input type="range" data-bind="date: addRange" />

<h2>Display date</h2>   
<strong data-bind="text: addStart" ></strong><br> 
<strong data-bind="text: timeLine" ></strong><br> 

<strong  type="color" data-bind="date: addColor"></strong> <br> 
<strong type="email" data-bind="date: addEmail"></strong><br> 
<strong type="url" data-bind="date: addUrl"></strong><br> 
<strong type="number" data-bind="date: addNumber"></strong><br> 
<strong type="range" data-bind="date: addRange"></strong><br>
```

```javascript
var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.addStart = ko.observable();       
    self.addStartDate = ko.observable();  // date
    self.addEndDate = ko.observable();    // date

    self.addColor = ko.observable();    // Color
    self.addEmail = ko.observable();    // Email
    self.addUrl = ko.observable();      // Url
    self.addNumber = ko.observable();   // Number
    self.addRange = ko.observable();    // Number

};
// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Treat those new `input` types as if they were `type='text'`, and just use the `value` binding. See:

```js
ko.applyBindings({ val1: ko.observable(), val2: ko.observable(), val3: ko.observable() });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

Date: <input type="date" data-bind="value: val1" />
<hr />
Color: <input type="color" data-bind="value: val2" />
<hr />
Email: <input type="email" data-bind="textInput: val3" />
<hr />
Etc.
<hr />
Confirm that view model actually changes / debug info:
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root)"></pre>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I am a bit confused with code, for what data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root)" stands for?

Comment: That's merely there for debugging purposes, so you can confirm that the input types are actually changing your view model.

Comment: Thanks it works! I am new in kockout.js, could you recommend any tutorials or any further steps in order to improve my knowledge?

Comment: [The KO website's tutorials](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/) were a big help when I started out. The rest I learned from reading the docs, experimentation, and going through [the source code](https://github.com/knockout/knockout) (the latter approach may not appeal to everyone though).